# Facebook apps using react native. Can't find ViewController.m

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook, react-native

I'm creating an app using react native and xcode. I've been following the set up instructions on facebook because I'm going to implement their login. However it says to add some code into ViewController.m in your xcode project, but when I initialize a new react project in terminal, it doesn't create one. I also can't find the ViewDidLoad method. Any suggestions?

In one of your app's ViewController.m files, and also in the AppDelegate.m file add:

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
```

In the ViewController.m file, add the following code to the viewDidLoad method:

```
FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
loginButton.center = self.view.center;
[self.view addSubview:loginButton];
```

Add this method in your app's AppDelegate.m file:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
             openURL:(NSURL *)url
   sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
          annotation:(id)annotation {
   return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                         openURL:url
                                               sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                      annotation:annotation];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved. React Native doesn't create ViewController files. If you are using React Native and the facebook app guide, disregard the 'Let's test out your integration' steps.